# Backup Exec - Restoring Offline Files Cache

Tags: restore, backupexec, offline-files

We have a set of mobile users who use Windows XP SP3 offline files to synchronize changes between network shares and their laptops.  We recently had an incident where a user's offline cache was not synchronizing and several weeks worth of changes were lost when the laptop was restaged.  Prior to the restage a full backup was performed using Backup Exec 2010 which completed successfully.  We assumed after the fact that the full backup would include the C:\Windows\CSC folder.  However, it appears that it did not.  At first, we could not see the CSC folder in the restore tree.  After enabling the server (W2K8R2x64) to see hidden files and folders and protected OS files, we can see the CSC folder within the Backup Exec restore tree, but there are no contents in the folder.  Performing a restore supports this view as no files are restored.

We realize that the files should have been synchronized (or checked for errors) before the restage.  Has anyone experienced similar problems backing up or restoring the offline file cache?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Backup Exec honors the system-wide "FilesNotToBackup" registry key (located at HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\BackupRestore\FilesNotToBackup) (see http://www.symantec.com/business/support/index?page=content&id=TECH31848 for details). By default, Windows XP includes a REG_MULTI_SZ entry there, "Client Side Cache", with the value "%SystemRoot%\csc* /s". This, I would suspect, is the reason your client side cache files didn't get backed-up.

Comment: That was it.  I hope we never again need to resort to a restore from CSC, but it's good to note for reference. Thanks!